# Glassfish 4.1 source code - full platform or web profile?

Tags: glassfish

I've downloaded the `Glassfish 4.1` source code from the [web](https://svn.java.net/svn/glassfish~svn/tags/4.1/). But what can I do to find out what version it is - full or web?

Answer (score 2):

It's all of it, what matters is how you build it. The source will contain everything except for external projects which are used, for example eclipselink or grizzly.

Here's a blog which tells you how to build it:
http://blog.c2b2.co.uk/2014/04/building-glassfish-from-source.html